# what are the ways of declaring dependencies in sbt

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

In sbt documentation, they have mentioned different ways of declaring project dependencies.

`libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision`

`libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision % configuration`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   groupID %% artifactID % revision,
   groupID %% otherID % otherRevision
)
```

However, when I created new Play2 framework with:

```
activator new HelloWorld play-scala
```

I could see following code in `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
jdbc,
anorm,
cache,
ws
)
```

How are they resolved (jdbc, anorm, cache, ws)? Are there some other way also to declare dependencies?

Comment: They are just vals imported from the play sbt plugin, which are made the same way `val jdbc = "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-jdbc" % "2.3.7"` (actually made with another function, but its the same).

Comment: how could I find these vals from previously defined plugins

Answer (score 3):

These are all examples of the one and same approach. The `libraryDependencies` key carries a sequence of artifacts, each of which is defined as

```
groupID % artifactID % revision % configuration
```

in most cases omitting the optional `configuration` that is commonly used to restrict dependencies to be added to the `"test"` only scope.

If you want to declare an individual dependency, you have

```
libraryDependencies += single
```

If you have multiple, you typically add them as a batch in a sequence:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(first, second, third)
```

In your last example, `jdbc`, `anorm` etc. have been previously defined as above, so you are just referring to these pre-existing values. You could also do that yourself:

```
lazy val myDep = groupID % artifactID % revision

libraryDependencies += myDep
```

To concatenate `groupID` and `artifactID`, there is a special operator `%%` instead of `%` which is useful for Scala libraries because they are often compiled against different versions of Scala, such as 2.10 and 2.11. The `%%` means that the Scala version is appended to the `artifactID`, relying on this common convention. I.e.

```
"com.foo" %% "bar" % "1.0"
```

Is equal to

```
"com.foo" % "bar_2.11" % "1.0"
```

if your project's Scala version is 2.11, or

```
"com.foo" % "bar_2.10" % "1.0"
```

if your Scala version is 2.10, etc.

Comment: Looking through my build files I could not see those vals defined. But, however, as @m-z has mentioned these are just imported from sbt-plugin. If yes, how could I know all these previously defined vals?

Comment: By reading the documentation.  For example, in the WS documentation, it tells you to add the "ws" dependency: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS. Also, all those keys are defined here: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlayImport.scala#L14.  You can see val ws = component("play-ws"), and then def component(id: String) = "com.typesafe.play" %% id % play.core.PlayVersion.current